# How can I migrate a sybase database to mysql?

Tags: mysql, migration, sybase

I've been tasked with migrating a fairly complex legacy Sybase database into a MySQL database and I have no idea where to start.  I can't use any off the shelf software, so I'm going to have to write some sort of script that takes all the info out of the Sybase database and puts it into MySQL.  Does anyone have any resources or thoughts on how to do this quickly, as I have very little experience with Sybase or MySQL.

Comment: What are *cots*?

Comment: Commercial off the shelf product.  So like I need to write it in house.

Comment: You should edit your question to say "off the shelf software" instead of cots....

Comment: It helps to know what product and version of db you are using, since Sybase is a company, not a database.

Comment: I don't mean this to be insulting, but if you have very little experience with Sybase or MySQL then why have you been tasked with this? A migration is a nontrivial task that requires expertise in both source and destination database products.

Answer (score 2):

Having no experience with Sybase, I suppose I would start by exporting the database schema into a text file, then go through and modify the `CREATE TABLE` statements manually until I am able to load the schema into MySQL.

Next, dump the data from each sybase table into CSV format file and then in the MySQL database, use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Depending on your database size, this could be a painfully slow option, but it is 'easy'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Sybase utility **ddlgen** to export the database structure, schema, objects, etc. from there you will have to go through the script files that are generated, and figure out what will run and what won't run.

Data can be exported by using the Sybase **bcp** utility, with whatever delimiters are necessary to import into your new database.

Both of these utilities are part of the Sybase installation, so they should be available for your use.

My answer here has more information on running **ddlgen**  and  **bcp** [Sybase Databse Migration from 11.5 to 15](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35475/sybase-databse-migration-from-11-5-to-15/)